# Hot reloading using webpack-serve with proxy(?)

Tags: webpack, hot-reload

I have a server serving a REST API + static content. Would it be possible to serve the static content with webpack-serve and let it manage hot reloading, while calls starting with "/api" are passed on to the REST API?

I tried setting this up by using a proxy and specifying content directory. That way webpack-serve would fall back to the REST API as it couldn't match the corresponding api paths on disk. I could GET the API endpoints in the browser, so the proxy worked, but POST:ing using AJAX gets 404:ed.

I can see in the terminal that changes in my source files are processed, but they don't propagate, neither hot nor at manual refresh (the js bundle is served as static content from disk, where it remains unchanged). Would greatly appreciate pointers!

My config:

```js
const path = require("path");
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
const proxy = require("http-proxy-middleware");
const convert = require("koa-connect");
const Router = require("koa-router");

const router = new Router();

const proxyOptions = {
  target: "http://localhost/",
  changeOrigin: true
};

router.get("*", convert(proxy(proxyOptions)));

module.exports = {
  watch: true,
  mode: "development",
  entry: "./internal-jsx/react-views.js",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve("static/scripts"),
    filename: "dev.bundle.js"
  },
  serve: {
    content: "./static",
    port: 8080,
    hot: {
      hot: true
    },
    add: (app, middleware, options) => {
      middleware.webpack();
      middleware.content();
      app.use(router.routes());
    }
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        enforce: "pre",
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: "eslint-loader"
      },
      { 
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: "style-loader",
          use: [
            {
              loader: "css-loader",
              options: {
                minimize: true,
                url: false
              }
            }
          ]
        })
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: "babel-loader"
      },
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: "babel-loader"
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin("../css/bundle.css")
  ]
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a middleware that forward the request to webpack server.

So, all request would go through your own server first. If it's an call to `/api` respond it by itself. If it's a request for static assets, forward it to the webpack server.